# Recursive sequence of integers

Tags: ruby

I want to generate a sequence of integers using recursion. If I enter `2`, the o/p should be `[2, 6, 22, 86, 342]`. I want to achieve this by using a recursive function. I have done the following using iteration:

```
n = gets
i = 0
a = Array.new
a.push(n)
while i < 4
  n = n * 4 - 2
  a.push(n)
  i = i + 1
end
p a
```

What changes should be made?

Comment: Note that `gets` returns a string, so you need `n = gets.to_i`. Also `gets` always appends `"\n"` to the end of the string entered by the user, so in other other applications you often need to remove that character. For example, if `"cats"` is entered, `str = gets #=> "cats\n"`, whereas `str = gets.chomp #=> "cats"`. `chomp` is not needed when `to_i` is used because `to_i` stops converting the string as soon as a character is encountered that is not a digit. For example, `"314159abc\n".to_i #=> "314159"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
def seq(num,limit=5) 
  return [] if limit < 1
  [num] + seq(num*4-2,limit - 1)
end
```

Then

```
seq(2,5)
#=> [2, 6, 22, 86, 342]
```

I would add some kind of an explanation but I am not really sure what to say. This is a recursive version of your proposed methodology.

We could also make this an Enumerator like so

```
enum= ->(num) { Enumerator.new do |y|
                  loop do 
                    y << num 
                    num = num*4-2
                  end
                end } 
seq = enum.(2)
seq.take(7)
#=> [2, 6, 22, 86, 342, 1366, 5462]
enum.(3).take(4)
#=> [3, 10, 38, 150]
```

Not exactly recursive per se but it is a common practice for building a number generator that can be reused.

Comment: The first method doesnt seem to work. n is not defined in seq(n*4-2). Replacing it with num gives an incorrect answer

Comment: @RafehIshtiaq the `n` should have been `num` that was a typo. What do you mean an incorrect answer you said *"if i enter 2 the o/p should be [2, 6, 22, 86, 342]"* and `seq(2) #=> [2, 6, 22, 86, 342]`

Answer (score -1):

Other option:

```
def sequence(n, res=[])
  return res if res.size == 5
  sequence(n*4-2, res << n)
end
```